# In Rust, how to use variable in format! macro?

Tags: rust, format

I have a very simple program:

```
fn main() {
    let y = format!("{:0>3}", 11);
    println!("{}", y);
}
```

The output is the string `011`. The problem is that the width specifier 3 in `{:0>3}` is coming from a variable like this:

```
fn main() {
    let x = 3usize;
    let y = format!("{:0>3}", 11);
    println!("{}", y);
}
```

How can I use variable `x` to replace `3` in `{:0>3}`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
fn main() {
    let x = 3;
    let y = format!("{:0>width$}", 11, width=x);
    println!("{}", y);
}
```

As it may be hard to remember the whole formatting syntax, it's a good idea to get used to find the **[reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#width)**.